# Firefox won't open using geckodriver

Tags: python, selenium, cygwin, python-3.7, geckodriver

I'm running my scripts through Cygwin and everything was working just fine until I had to reinstall it. Now my script freezes as soon as I try to open the browser, not giving any error. I'm using geckodriver v0.25.0 and firefox 66.0.4. Everything is the same as before as far as I know.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.txt", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="./geckodriver.exe")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1476, in _execute_child
    part = os.read(errpipe_read, 50000)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Code used

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="./geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("https://inventwithpython.com")
```

Comment: Please add the code you are using to open the browser.

Comment: Oh, right. I forgot. Done.

Comment: Did you try gekodriver 24 or 26? https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: Yes, I used the 26 before and it didn't work.

Comment: Try version 24.

Comment: Tried both now and still no luck.

Comment: Try changing the `executable_path` to start from your C drive.

Comment: No luck either. I get a No such file or directory error. But as I mentioned, I've always used "./geckodriver.exe" with sucess.

Comment: `No such file issue` is weird. Just to clear this up try putting your geckodriver.exe on your C drive get then setting executable_path to `executable_path="C:\\geckodriver.exe"`

Comment: That's what I've done before which led to the error.